# COMO PODRIA EMPLEAR EL COMBOBOX ANIDADO

Tags: java

Buenas me podrían ayudar hacer un comboBox anidado en la cual en el comboBox de Nivel este registrado Básico, Intermedio y Avanzado, cuando seleccione Básico me muestre en el comboBox de ciclo I, II y III; Intermedio (IV, V, VI, VII) y Avanzado (VIII, VIIII, X).[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual es el problema?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]!  Tu pregunta incumple algunas normas con las cuales nos regimos aquí. Léete [ask], [tour] y [example].  No se ve lo que has intentado para conseguir tu propósito, tan solo muestras el aspecto del formuario sin una línea de código y si no muestras los errores que tienes no podremos ayudarte, lo siento.

Comment: Jonathan. También cambia la etiqueta. Lo que muestras es Java, no Javascript. Lo que debes hacer es: 1- Obtener el Id del combobox padre en el evento que se dispara cuando cambia. 2 - Obtener la lista de elementos hijos relacionados con ese Id. 3 -Llenar el combobox hijo con esa lista. 4- ??? 5- Profit.